# viewing direction vectors are not parallel in orthographic projection

Tags: projections

I did some math with orthographic projection matrix to compute viewing direction vectors in screen space.

I thought all viewing direction vectors should be parallel in orthographic projection because, in orthographic projection, eye sight lines will be always parallel.

However, the math doesn't show the parallel directions.

```cpp
    QMatrix4x4 proj;
    proj.ortho(-100, 100, -100, 100, 1, 1001);
    qDebug() << "projection matrix:" << proj;
    auto inv = proj.inverted();
    qDebug() << "inverse projection matrix:" << inv;
    qDebug() << "viewing direction at bottom left corner:" << inv.map(QVector3D(-1, -1, 0)).normalized();
    qDebug() << "viewing direction at top right corner  :" << inv.map(QVector3D(1, 1, 0)).normalized();
```

This is small code to compute what I mentioned and the results are:

```
projection matrix: QMatrix4x4(type:Translation,Scale
      0.01         0         0         0         
         0      0.01         0         0         
         0         0    -0.002    -1.002         
         0         0         0         1         
)
inverse projection matrix: QMatrix4x4(type:Translation,Scale
       100         0         0         0         
         0       100         0         0         
         0         0      -500      -501         
         0         0         0         1         
)
viewing direction at bottom left corner: QVector3D(-0.192094, -0.192094, -0.962393)
viewing direction at top right corner  : QVector3D(0.192094, 0.192094, -0.962393)
```

Here, viewing direction vectors at opposite corners don't look parallel.

Did I do something wrong here? Or, did I misunderstand orthographic projection?
Why can't I get parallel rays here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only transferred a single point from projection space to view space.

But you are interested in directions, so you need to convert two points to be able to see the view direction.

```
//check view direction of lower left corner 
vec4 p0_0 = vec4(-1,-1,0,1);
vec4 p0_1 = vec4(-1,-1,1,1);

//check view direction of upper right corner
vec4 p1_0 = vec4(1,1,0,1);
vec4 p1_1 = vec4(1,1,1,1);

Vec4 ip0_0 = inverprojection * p0_0
Vec4 ip0_1 = inverprojection * p0_1
Vec4 ip1_0 = inverprojection * p1_0
Vec4 ip1_1 = inverprojection * p1_1
```

So we have two points per view direction test.

```
Vec4 viewDir0 = ip0_0 - ip0_1
Vec4 viewDir1 = ip1_0 - ip1_1
```

Last step is to compare viewDir0 with viewDir1

Comment: You can do exactly the same with perspective projections... But then you need to divide the outcomming vectors by their 4th component...